# Non-object file targets in autotools for inclusion in C source files

Tags: c, makefile, autotools

How can I tell `lib/Makefile.am` to produce non-`.o` targets out of certain input files (here `.txt`) and tell it to do this *before* compiling regular C source files?

Background: I have a bunch of text files (`.txt`) as input along with other C source files. I would like to process them with `xxd` to produce an C array initializer list which gets included by one of the C source files. Thus, text file processing should happen before compiling `.c` files.

In the C file I would include the processed `.inc` file:

```
#include "data.inc"
```

I get this far:

```
SUFFIXES = .txt
.txt.$(OBJEXT):
    $(XXD) -i $< @top_builddir@/include/$*.inc
```

The problem is that the makefile assumes a `.o` file being generated out of the rule (`.txt` --> `.o`) which is not what I need. I need to tell it that `.inc` is the final form and that it lives in the `top_builddir`. What would be the preferred way to do this?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Sources Also, if you don't want it to think you want a `.txt.o`, Don't state that as a goal.

Comment: This would generate the `.inc` file in the `/lib` directory where the `#include` statement does not find it. How can it be placed into the `/include` directory?